# Use 2 forms (user/admin) with Form Type in Silex

Tags: php, forms, symfony, silex

I'm new with Silex.
I'm using [this](https://github.com/bpesquet/OC-MicroCMS/tree/iteration-13) script.

I added a new field "status" in the comment table to validate the comment by the admin.

In [this](https://github.com/bpesquet/OC-MicroCMS/blob/iteration-13/src/Form/Type/CommentType.php) script we have a Form type for comment.

I want to modify this file, to show the textarea if it's a simple user and the textarea + choice field for change the status of comment if it's an admin.

I can't use the role_admin check :

```
if ($app['security.authorization_checker']->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'))
```

How do you suggest, to simply show different form depending on the ROLE user ?

Answer (score 0):

you have there some options.

1. you can pass the container in your formtype. $app is the DI-container so you only can access it, when you pass it in your classes.
2. Create a second type, which extends your formtype or which only makes the checkbox. in your controller you should access $app and then make the choose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will check it. I know that I can add more formtype but I don't want to have 50 formtype for all specific forms I can add in the future. Maybe the first option is more optimize.